# NoReverseMatch at ... django issue

Tags: python, django

When I try to delete a post Django shows this error.

```
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_post' with arguments
'(<Post: "POST-TITLE-HERE">,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/table/post/delete/$
']
```

How can I repair it?

Important parts of my code are as follows:

views.py:

```
def delete_post(request, slug):
    post= get_object_or_404(Post, post=slug)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('post:post_detail')
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post= models.CharField(max_length=15)
    description_post = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post:post_delete", kwargs={"slug": self.post})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

HTML template ( delete link)

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'board:delete_post' slug=post %}">
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^table/post/delete/$', views.delete_post, name='delete_post')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *When I try delete my post Django show me error*. What error, specifically? Your question is much more helpful if you provide us with a descriptive error message (not necessarily long). Also, shouldn't you be specifying an ID field in the URL regex? Something like `url(r'^table/post/delete/(?P<post_id>\d+)`.

Comment: It seems the problem is you can't redirect to post_detail because you have deleted the post you want redirect and it does'nt exist anymore.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The url pattern you have setup for `delete_post` is missing a named group.

```
url(r'^table/post/delete/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', views.delete_post, name='delete_post')
```

Also, ensure the slug for the post is used in your template. I assume your post instance has a `slug` field.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'board:delete_post' slug=post.slug %}">
```

Comment: Thanks! It working, but now I have problem with return redirect('post:post_detail') . Post has been deleted but Django not redirect to...

Comment: I think you want to return a redirect to a list of posts not detail after deleting a post.

Answer (score 0):

Make the position/keyword arguments clear is more important. So that you can use either of them. FYI, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse